# How to a data from the element that i clicked using "This" in JS?

Tags: javascript, web

I want to get a data from the element that i clicked using `this` in JavaScript?

but insisted of the data it's return `undefined`.

```js
function jj(){
    let yty = this.num;
    console.log(yty);
}
```

```css
li {
width:200px;
}
```

```html
<button num="2" onclick="jj()">3</button>
```

Comment: if you're adding `onclick` attribute, the context of the function is not changed to the element. You're giving the code to call which is `jj` and it's just executed normally in the global context, so `this` would be `window` in that case (loose mode + undefined). You either need to use `addEventListener` to attach the callback or pass `this` into it `onclick=jj(this)` and use the passed in argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this` as function parameter

```js
function jj(e) {
  let yty = e.getAttribute('num');
  console.log(yty);
}
```

```css
li {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button num="2" onclick="jj(this)">3</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `this` from HTML itself and use `getAttribute()` to get the attribute value you want

```js
function jj(btn) {
  console.log(btn.getAttribute('num'));
}
```

```css
li {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button num="2" onclick="jj(this)">3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
<button num=2 onclick="getVal(event)">Click</button>
```

in .js

```
function getVal(event){
    let value=event.target.getAttribute('num');
    console.log(value);
}
```